# Reset external diff tool per command

Tags: git, diff, git-config, git-difftool

I've recently installed a new diff tool ([difftastic](https://github.com/Wilfred/difftastic)), which messes with my habit of copying diffs to clipboard (or to file) to send those:

```
[diff]
    external = difft # As per https://difftastic.wilfred.me.uk/git.html
```

```
                                | what I want | what I get |
                                | ----------- | ---------- |
$ git diff                      | difft       | difft      |
$ git diff > some-file          | git diff    | difft      |
$ GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF= git diff   | git diff    | error      |
```

My end goal is to have a single command to which I can pass usual git diff arguments and get the original (something like `git diff --internal` basically.

Eventually I'll go upstream to difftastic and offer a PR fixing that (e.g. difftastic defaulting to using git if piped), but I'm almost certain I don't understand correctly git's [`diff.external`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffexternal) and `difftool*` configs. And I don't know **how to reset `diff.external` per command**

Comment: The manual seems pretty helpful, https://difftastic.wilfred.me.uk/git.html And of course an alias can make things simpler to type.

Comment: @matt sorry I must be a bit dull then, but I've read this manual many times and I'm not sure how it might help with my question... I want to default to git diff being difft (hence the `git config --global diff.external difft`), but have a solution to override that when piping, and that is where I struggle. Sorry if the question is not clear enough, I could try editing further..

Comment: That is why I suggest, instead of defaulting, use a git alias so you can easily summon difft using git syntax when desired...? But maybe that's not useful?

Comment: If possible I'd like to keep difftastic as default as there are a lot of git commands that  are affected by `difftools`, and the only one I care about *not* being difftasting is `git diff` ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial solution I found thanks to matt's comments on the question:

```bash
git diff --no-ext-diff
```

Yet I'm sure there are cleaner solution to better choose between either git diff is piped, hence use normal patch or git diff isn't hence do the fancy thing.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're saying about "a lot of git commands", but I still did it the other way: I created aliases, one for each command for which I want `difft` as a possibility. So for example `git difft ...` is just an alias for the rather clumsy `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=difft git diff ...`. And so on. So that way if I want old-fashioned `git diff` I just say `git diff`.

Comment: @matt I've clarified my intention a lot more, and since this completely changed from before, I decided to make it another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73211265/6320039, hope this is clearer.

Comment: Good idea. Might want to delete this one. :)

Comment: Please don't delete this one, it's a useful question and a useful answer.