# Allow different behaviour for external diff tool if git command is piped

Tags: bash, git, git-diff

I'm using [difftastic](https://github.com/Wilfred/difftastic) for better visualisation of my diffs in my terminal. Which means my config is

```bash
git config --global diff.external difft
```

However, when the output is not a tty, I'd rather have git use it's internal diff tool (e.g. the same as doing `git diff --no-ext-diff` but without me having to type that). So basically

```bash
$ git diff # please use difft
# git diff | cat # please use no external diff tool
```

However, I'm struggling with that because I cannot find a way to bubble up this information to my diff tool. Let's say I have some pseudo diff tool that actually just shows content of argv, first line of argc and check if its stdout is a tty:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "io/console"
require "logger"
require "pp"

f = File.open("mygitdiff.log", "a")
f.puts("\n---- #{Time.now}")
PP.pp(ARGV, f)
PP.pp(gets, f)
f.puts("STDOUT.tty? #{STDOUT.tty?}")
```

This script prints the same log whether I am piping or not:

```
---- 2022-08-02 18:57:30 +0200
["bin/new",
 "/var/folders/v5/1p20ylgn0db5621r8wtdg5v80000gn/T//37FrIz_new",
 "c2a6c5aafc3485755f774cb3efcae4a2819a777f",
 "100755",
 "bin/new",
 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "100755"]
"#!/usr/bin/env ruby\n"
STDOUT.tty? false

---- 2022-08-02 18:57:34 +0200
["bin/new",
 "/var/folders/v5/1p20ylgn0db5621r8wtdg5v80000gn/T//jaEmlN_new",
 "c2a6c5aafc3485755f774cb3efcae4a2819a777f",
 "100755",
 "bin/new",
 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "100755"]
"#!/usr/bin/env ruby\n"
STDOUT.tty? false
```

As you can see there is no major difference there. Do you have any other idea how to achieve that goal?

Also note that the first line of argv, I don't understand at all what it means

Comment: The argv values are described in the [top level `git` manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) under the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable. Basically `git diff` may have to extract some readable-only-by-Git internal blob object content, and if it does that, it drops the extracted file into a temp file like `/var/folders/v5/1p20y....`, so that the external program only has to read an ordinary file, not some weird compressed Git internal magic.

Comment: Side note: rather than doing some deep magic with std(in,out,err)-is-a-tty, it's probably wiser for you to set up a Git alias that runs `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=whatever git diff` (e.g., set `alias.dt` to `!GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=...`). Your script can then invoke difftastic on the two files. Then just run `git dt` to get a difftastic diff, and `git diff` to get a regular diff.

Comment: Hey, thanks! My goal is to avoid having an alias though... But I guess git doesn't give this option then. I guess I could have a last resort of having a command that wraps git, and set an env variable when it is piped, which I could then transmit to my diff tool

Comment: Yes, name a tool `gd` for instance, and then have `gd` check for stdout-is-a-tty and run whichever command you want.

Comment: @torek "it's probably wiser for you to set up a Git alias that runs GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=whatever git diff" Note that that's exactly what I said in my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/73205880/341994. The OP remains unpersuaded.

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit stubborn sometimes, but I think I have it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create a new `git` bin file, and put it in your path somewhere **before** the original git path (for me `/usr/bin`). The wrapper will decide whether an external diff tool should be used depending on the stdout state:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (isatty(fileno(stdout)) && isatty(fileno(stderr))) {
        setenv("GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF", "difft", 1);
    }

    execvp("/usr/bin/git", argv);
}
```